# передача переменных в корзину

Tags: opencart

мне нужно передать в массив с продуктами id каждого товара.  пробывал в моделе order.php добавить в массив значение. но ничего не выходит. В корзине в массиве products есть значение ['key'] кто может сказать как оно формируется?
opencart 2.0.1.1

направьте пожалуйста  в правильном  направлении

после небольшой проверки что это модель не передает в корзину параметр key , тоесть мне нужна другая модель. только не ясно какая. в папке модули нет дополнительной модели для корзины.

Comment: При добавлении в корзину через Ajax запрашивается страница с php кодом передавая туда данные о продукте (product_id ...).php код заносит данные в databasename.orders таблицу.А когда переходим на страницу orders то делается выборка всех записей из этой таблицы

Comment: подскажите, как добавить передачу id товаров в корзину?

Comment: А оно чо не добавляется при нажатие на add to cart button ?

Comment: я настраиваю динамический ремеркетинг и мне нужно передавать айди товаров. а когда я вывожу переменную products в корзине, там нет id, есть только key из индефикационных значений/ вот такой  array(10) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(39) "YToxOntzOjEwOiJwcm9kdWN0X2lkIjtpOjY0O30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден. очень странно но нужный мне массив находится в контроллере
ControllerCommonCart
    $data['products'][]
добавляем строчку 'id'        => $product['product_id'],